# Autocomplete in Elasticsearch

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, elasticsearch

I am getting all the fields in autocomplete elastic search.I want those fields which have related values only.Is it doable?

I tried:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "multi_match": {
                        "query": "B",
                        "fields": [
                            "City",
                            "MLSNumber"
                        ],
                        "zero_terms_query": "all",
                        "boost": 3
                    }
                },
                {
                    "multi_match": {
                        "query": "B",
                        "fields": [
                            "City",
                            "MLSNumber"
                        ],
                        "zero_terms_query": "all",
                        "fuzziness": 0,
                        "boost": 1
                    }
                }
            ],
            "minimum_should_match": 1
        }
    },
    "sort": [
        {
            "_score": "desc"
        }
    ],
    "from": 0,
    "size": 25
}
```

Comment: @ToKen:Thanks for editing

Comment: You're welcome, I'd help you if I'd known `elastic`